# Accessing a sparse matrix efficiently

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I have this huge sparse matrix A of size 2 million by 10 thousand. I want to index particular 1000 rows (index) from this matrix.

If I do

B = A(index,:);

it takes some time. Is there a better quick way to access the rows of this matrix efficiently?

Comment: are the indices consequtive? If they are not, what you wrote is probably the fastest way.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the underlying column-wise data structure used to store sparse matrices internally, it may be better to transpose the matrix and then apply your operations column-wise. The final matrix can then be re-transposed.

See the last section in the [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/sparse-matrix-operations.html) on sparse matrix operations.